# How to hide a batch file after a command was issued

Tags: batch-file, cmd, hide, restart, notepad

I have made a program in notepad which when runs allows the user to choose one of a select amount of options. Each option is a time that essentially counts down until when it hits 0 the computer locks itself.

**Problems:**

This has been created to allocate a set amount of time for my little brother however it can easily be stopped by just manually closing the program.

I wanted to know if I could therefore make it so after choosing an option the program would hide itself by running in the background or so if it is manually closed it would reopen and carry on counting down thank you.

**Provided Example Code:**

```
@echo off

cls

title Shutdown timer

color 0a

:start

echo

echo Choose Your Time allocated

echo 1. 35 Minutes

echo 2. 65 Minutes

echo 3. 95 Minutes

echo 4. 125 Minutes

echo 5. 1 Minutes

set /p choice=Type which number for your choice

if not '%choice%'== set choice=%choice:~0,1%

if '%choice%'=='1' goto :Choice1

if '%choice%'=='2' goto :Choice2

if '%choice%'=='3' goto :Choice3

if '%choice%'=='4' goto :Choice4

If '%choice%'=='5' goto :Choice5

echo "%choice%" is not a valid option. Please try again
```

Comment: If you use the choice command, which is why it's there, users can ONLY enter a valid command. See `choice /?`. `Set /p` is for other types of input.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking to baby-poof a batch script? A simple solution is to simply hide the command window. This can be done by using a `.VBS` command shell to hide the command prompt process. Original post [here](https://superuser.com/a/62646/924296).

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False
```

Above is the script to hide command windows in `VBS`. You can use this script by calling `wscript.exe "Script" "Batch File"`. Pretty simple and easy way to do it without 3'rd party tools.

I combined your script to allow to create, export, use, and delete these files. Your Main shutdown script will also need exported to a new batch file to be called to by the VBS script. This can be done using a code block bellow

```
Rem | Create Timer.bat
(
    Echo TIMEOUT /T %Time% /NOBREAK
    Echo rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation
    Echo DEL "%%~f0"
)>> %Temp%\Timer.bat
```

This will create a new batch file containing the shutdown or lock commands. In this case `rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation` will lock the workstation after X minutes by `TIMEOUT /T`

**StartTimmer.bat:**

```
@echo off
title Shutdown timer
color 0a

:start
cls
echo Choose Your Time allocated:
echo(
echo 1. 35 Minutes
echo 2. 65 Minutes
echo 3. 95 Minutes
echo 4. 125 Minutes
echo 5. 1 Minutes
echo(
set /p "choice=Type which number for your choice: "

if "%choice%"=="1" set "choice=35" & goto ChoiceSellected
if "%choice%"=="2" set "choice=65" & goto ChoiceSellected
if "%choice%"=="3" set "choice=95" & goto ChoiceSellected
if "%choice%"=="4" set "choice=125" & goto ChoiceSellected
If "%choice%"=="5" set "choice=1" & goto ChoiceSellected

goto start

:ChoiceSellected

Echo Now Starting Timmer For %choice% Minutes

Rem | Do math - Covert Seconds To Minutes
Set /a "Time=%choice% * 60"

Rem | Create Timer.bat
(
    Echo TIMEOUT /T %Time% /NOBREAK
    Echo rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation
    Echo DEL "%%~f0"
)>> %Temp%\Timer.bat

Rem | Export Hide Script & Use it
Echo CreateObject^("Wscript.Shell"^).Run """" ^& WScript.Arguments^(0^) ^& """", 0, False>> Hide.vbs
wscript.exe "%~dp0Hide.vbs" "%Temp%\Timer.bat"
del "%~dp0Hide.vbs"

goto :EOF
```

---

For help on any of the commands do the following:

- `call /?`
- `set /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `find /?`
- So on.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the information its been helpful however i'm quite new to programming using batch codes and don't know much about it. I understand most of what you have put and from what I have read from the link provided but I can't get it to work. I am certain this is because I have the program with the full code written where as I only provided a small piece as an example.

Comment: @MacaulayThroop Did you copy & paste the entire script as is into a `.bat` file? If it did not work I would type `wscript.exe` into an empty command prompt and see if its a valid command. If it says unkown command, you will need to put it's file path in the batch file. Example change `wscript.exe` to `C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe`. Same goes with `rundll32.exe`.